# LP constraint for ensuring used palletspaces are next to each other

Tags: linear-programming, constraints

Hi math stackexchange :)

I am having trouble formulating a mathematical constraint which ensures that if a retailer is allocated to multiple palletspaces, then those palletspaces are next to one another. Shops can only use one port.

**I have the following input parameters:**

1. SL denoting shop labels (i)
2. PL denoting port labels (j)
3. PSL denoting palletspace labels (l)
4. D_jl denoting the distance from port j to palletspace l
5. S =range(0, len(SL)
6. P =range(0, len(PL)
7. PS =range(0, len(PSL)

**And the following variables:**

1. $x_{ijl} =$ 1 if shop i is using pallet space l through port j, 0 else
2. $i_{il} =$ 1 if shop i is using pallet space l, 0 else

**How I imagine the solution**

Introduce new variables:

*Starting pallet space*
$s_l=\sum_{l \in PS} l*x_{ijl}$

*Ending pallet space*
$e_l=\sum_{l \in PS} l*x_{ijl}$

*LP constraint*

$e_l - s_l \le \sum_{l in PS} l*i_(il)$,  $\forall i \in S$

**Problem**

However, it just doesn't seem to work.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Can you reformat your question, introducing MathJax formatting? That would make your question more readable.

Comment: Thank you @Dominique, I didn't know how to do that but now I do :) I have made it more readable now

Comment: Your formulas for $s_l$ and $e_l$ are the same.